# JIRA: How to make a webhook fire for only a single transition, of a workflow?

Tags: git, jenkins, jira, webhooks

**Scenario is**:

Git -> JIRA -> Jenkins

A commit in Git, must change an issue status in JIRA, which in turn, should trigger a build for a job in Jenkins.

**Method Tried**:

1. I created a WebHook in JIRA. This webhook contains the URL for a Jenkins job.
2. Attached this WebHook to a Work Flow in JIRA, as a *post function*.
3. The workflow is a simple one. It says: [InReview]-->[InProgress]-(Aprrove)->[Done]
4. The webhook is attached to the transition from [InProgress] to [Done]
5. IssueKey and Issue-Updated has been mentioned in the WebHook. IssueKey will make that WebHook work only for a specific issue. Issue-Updated is an event that will fire WebHook, when that specific issue is updated.

Now, when I do a Git commit, status of Jira issue changes from InReview to InProgress and an Approve button appears. When I check in Jenkins, a build is triggered because of this issue change. Again I'll go back to JIRA, hit the Approve button, Issue status changes from InProgress to Done and this too triggers a build in Jenkins.

My requirement is that the Jenkins build should happen only on InProgress to Done status change. I am not able to point out the reason that why the InReview to InProgress transition triggers a Jenkins build.

Any pointers on this would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled scm polling in jenkins?

Comment: Hello @GuyBouallet, thank you for the suggestion. I tried it. But it didnt solve the problem. I guess I just resolved this roadblock, with the help of JQL. I'll mention the solution below.

Comment: Have you checked the `Changelog matcher` configuration in Jenkins? You can configure the `jira-trigger-plugin` as such that the build is only triggered if the status sent to Jenkins is `Done`. Check the plugin readme/help for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of hit and trials, finally **JQL** did the trick for me. I edited the WebHook as follows:

In the **Events** (Issue related events) section, which says (Events for issues and worklogs. You can specify a JQL query to send only events triggered by matching issues.), I entered:

`issuekey = "Issue-ID" AND status = "In Review"`

"Issue-ID" mentioned in above line of code is for reference. In actual, its a 3 lettered word followed by the issue number, like : **ABC-1**

This will trigger the action(webhook) for a transition from a particular status. The moral of the story is: All transitions which source from `"this value"`  in JQL query `status="this value"`, will fire the webhook.

**Edit 1:** To make the webhook more transition specific, so that it fires for one and only one transition, we can use the JQL as:

```
status CHANGED FROM "In Progress" TO "Open"
```