# JQL Changed FROM/TO doesn't fire the Webhook event

Tags: jenkins, webhooks, jira-plugin, jql, jenkins-jira-trigger

Basically, this is what I am trying to do:
[StatusChangedInKanban.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451616/jira-how-to-make-a-webhook-fire-for-only-a-single-transition-of-a-workflow) And I tried the suggestion mentioned there. 

I have created webhook to fire Jenkins using "jira-trigger-webhook-receiver" plugin.

The following JQL works(filters the event to kick the build in Jenkins):
project = MyProject AND type in (Bug, ...).

But **NOT** the following(always kicks build in Jenkins, as if "All Issues"):
status changed FROM "In Progress" TO Done. (I tried different combination of it). Seems like it doesn't even know what "changed from/to" is. 
However it shows in the operator drop-down when I type in the "Issue related events" for JQL.

Looks like I am missing some configuration somewhere.
And I tried that workflow method mentioned in the above link as well. Didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Is the build triggering on issues that have already built?  2) Is the build triggering on issues that have gone from status-before-in-progress TO "In Progress"?

Comment: @HeyZiko-If I use "status = Done", the event is filtered based on this logic, which means the build is triggered if I move the issue/story from "Done" column. But if I use "status CHANGED FROM/TO", it acts as if there is no filter at all. So, it will trigger the build for everything.

Comment: Have you checked `jira-trigger-plugin`'s Changelog matcher option? You can add a `JIRA Field Matcher` for Status field, hence doing the filtering in Jenkins instead of JIRA. Check the plugin's README / help for more information.

Comment: @ceilfors- That is what I ended up doing. I filtered by "project" and "type" in JIRA side and "Field Matcher" in the Jenkins side. Any idea how to AND multiple JIRA fields in Jenkins side?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a STATUS CHANGED FROM or STATUS CHANGED TO query in JQL, it looks at the entire history of the issue, not the most recent change. Therefore, you're getting **everything** that ever changed from "in progress" to "done".

Since you're dependent on the webhook, you can trust that the automation kicks in every X minutes or days. Thus, your query should probably look like this:

```
project = MyProject AND type in (Bug, X, Y) 
AND status changed FROM "In Progress" TO Done AFTER -1d
AND status = Done
```

Line by line, this is what you're telling JIRA:

> For Bug, X, and Y issues in MyProject
>
> Find everything that changed from In-Progress to Done in the past day

(you can adjust the -1d to match your automation frequency, like -5m for the past 5 minutes)

> And is currently Done

(because if you have a subsequent status like Closed then you don't want it to build)

Comment: @HeyZiko-I will give it a try.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, it doesn't kick the build now when I use the following: status CHANGED FROM "In Progress" TO Done AFTER -1m AND status = Done. I tried -2m, -5m. Doesn't kick the build in Jenkins.